# Cual es la ventaja o desventaja de hacer una ventana modal de esta forma?

Tags: javascript, modal

He visto muchos plugins que permiten integrar ventanas modales en nuestras webs, los cuales contienen mucho código javascript.

En la pagina w3school tienen un tipo de modal hecha con  poco código javascript, utilizando `GetElementById`, lo cual es parte de javascript.

Mi duda es ¿es mejor utilizar la segunda opción? por asunto de no sobrecargar el sitio o ¿la primera opción es mejor, por qué?

Cuando digo sobrecargar me refiero a mucho código. ¿Hay ventajas, cuáles?

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el código de uno y otro para comparar?

Comment: Realmente lo de mucho o poco código va a depender de muchas cosas como la funcionalidad o el comportamiento esperado. No es lo mismo simplemente mostrar/ocultar el modal, que crearlo de manera dinámica, con animaciones, con múltiples configuraciones...

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Entiendo.Yo muestro el modal y le pongo animaciones con css3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las ventajas de utilizar un plugin son:

- Código ya implementado de la funcionalidad que requieres (en este caso, una ventana modal).
- En muchos casos, parámetros de configuración y multitud de opciones.

Las desventajas de utilizar un plugin son:

- Puede no estar pensado exactamente para tu caso de uso (no hace exactamente lo que quieres y se tiene menos control sobre él).
- Desconocimiento del código (puede ser ineficiente, por ejemplo). Es importante comprobar la popularidad del plugin para no "quedarse colgado".

Por lo tanto, no hay uno mejor que otro, sino que depende de tus necesidades. Si, por ejemplo, solo necesitas mostrar y cerrar una ventana, no debería tomar mucho tiempo escribirlo en javascript plano, pero si necesitas más funcionalidades, puede valer la pena dedicar unos minutos a buscar un plugin y no preocuparse por la "cantidad de javascript", porque posiblemente escribir algo parecido también requeriría de esa cantidad de código.